# ASP.NET Ajax Tool Kit vs third party controls for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using Ajax Control Toolkit and I make use of these controls. I am just wondering if there any free third party controls that can be used for .net. I believe the Telerik product is a paid version. Because I tried it and a message appears on top of my page addressing you are still using demo version. Later my page design breaks.

Has anyone else here used Telerik or other third party controls for free?

Comment: Ok but what's your requirement of project if you are using some telerik control there will be some `advantages` and `disadvantages` same for ajax its all depends upon website your are building + requirement+ analysis

Comment: I am trying to use a scheduler for my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/), there is [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com), which have some "free" controls along with controls that cost money. Both companies create useful UI controls that can make development quicker.

However, there is also jQuery and the many available plugins - this route will give you more control on what can be achieved in the UI, and you are not tied into a single vendor. This route often innovates quicker than either DevExpress or Telerik.

Comment: So probably I should be looking for Jquery plugins which better fits into this.

Comment: I would recommend that route yes. If you ever want to move the application to MVC it will be easier too.